# How to apply $ne to document fields inside an array?

Tags: mongodb

This is my document set:

```
{ model: "BMW", owners: [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Sarah" }] }
{ model: "Ford", owners: [{ name: "Peter" }] }
```

I need to select all cars, which are not owned by "Peter". This is what I'm doing:

```
db.find({ '$ne': ['$owners.name', 'Peter'] })
```

I'm getting them all, including the one owned by `"Peter"`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) command is the following:

```
db.collection.find({ "owners.name": { "$ne":  "Peter" }})
```

The above command should work for you.

Comment: Because that's the syntax for $ne command - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

Comment: it's worth to check also mongodb's aggregation syntax for $ne https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/ these differences drive me crazy